# Anonymous can see protected area

Tags: symfony, silex

I am developing an app in Silex with Symfony Security component. Anonymous users should be able to access every point of app except admin section (^/admin).

What am I doing wrong? Anonymous can still access admin section. I have followed some other answers on SO to get to this points but now I am stuck.

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array
(
    'general' => array
    (
        'pattern' => '^/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array
        (
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login_check',
            'default_target_path' => '/admin',
            'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
        ),
        'logout' => array
        (
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
            'target_url' => '/'
        ),
        'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
            return new UserProvider($app['db']);
        })
    )
);

// @todo - find out why anonymous can see admin panel
$app['security.access_control'] = array
(
    array('path' => '^/login', 'role' => 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
    array('path' => '^/admin', 'role' => 'ROLE_USER'),
);

$app['security.role_hierarchy'] = array
(
    'ROLE_ADMIN' => array('ROLE_USER'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the `security.access_control` (which seemed ignored now) to `security.access_rules` (which threw error of "access_rules" being unknown property previously) and now it seems to work:

`$app['security.access_rules'] = array
(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_USER'),
);`

Answer (score 0):

look at the docs
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#basic-example-http-authentication

```
'access_control' => array(
    array('path' => '^/admin/', 'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    // Include the following line to also secure the /admin path itself
    // array('path' => '^/admin$', 'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
),
```

its either ^/admin/ or ^/admin$  not ^/admin

Comment: Neither of the above work. In the init action of the admin controller `$this->app['security']->getToken()->getUser()` outputs `anon.`. ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN should be able to access /admin, but anonymous users not.